# Click outside of Navbar detected

Tags: javascript, dom, navbar, event-listener

I have no idea why this is not working. I have my "mainNav" class set to display {none}. My "active" class has a display {block}. My navToggle works fine before I add the window.eventlistener into my JS. But once as add the window.addeventlistener it stops working.

```
const navTransition = () => {
    const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
    const mainNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links');

navToggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
    mainNav.classList.toggle('active');
});

window.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (!evt.target.matches('.nav-links') && (!evt.target.matches('.main-nav'))) {
        mainNav.classList.remove('active');
    };
});
```

};

```
navTransition();



<nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nav-toggle">
        <span>+</span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you show me the html please? Only the vital parts of it though.

Comment: can you show your html code or a working snippet would be great .

Comment: @AlphaHowl i have added the HTML. sorry if it looks funny i am still new to stack overflow. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @JagadishLenka i have added the HTML underneath the JavaScript. Thank you helping.

Answer (score 1):

Your `window.onclick` event is causing this logic error. Every time you click on the page, it will hide the navbar. Even when you click on the `.nav-toggle` this will trigger the `window.onclick` and therefore hide the navbar. The window click event will always be triggered after the nav-toggle click event because the click event bubbles through each element and into the parent element. So the "path" of that click event will be `.nav-toggle`, then `.navbar` and finally the `html`, document and `window`. As you can see, the click events for `window` are triggered last - after all others, so even if the nav-toggle adds the `actve` class to your navbar, the `window.onclick` event will remove it after a few milliseconds.

To fix this you could either change the `window.onclick` event for a `window.onmousedown`, which will be triggered before the click of `nav-toggle`, or add a condition to your current `window.onclick` event to check if `event.target` is the `nav-toggle`. The latter way seems more clean to me, and I have done so in this snippet.

```js
const navTransition = () => {
    const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
    const mainNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links');


window.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if(evt.target.matches('.nav-links') || evt.target.matches('.main-nav') || evt.target.matches(".nav-toggle") || evt.target.closest(".nav-toggle")) {
      return;
    }
    mainNav.classList.remove('active');
});

navToggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
    mainNav.classList.toggle('active');
});


};

navTransition();
```

```css
.main-nav.active {
  display: block !important;
}
.main-nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
    <ul class="main-nav active">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nav-toggle">
        <span>+</span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: wow! thank you so much for explaining the logic behind why it doesn't work. I don't want to just know that a solution works, i like to understand WHY it works. thank you again, you have been a big help.

Comment: No problem :D .